# Lottery Probability Confusion

Tags: probability

(A) Estimate the probability of getting $4$ out of $6$ numbers correct in a lottery system that uses $49$ white balls numbered $1$ through $49.$

(B) If a red "powerball" is chosen from a group of $10$ balls numbered $0-9$ is added to part A (after picking the $6$ from the group of $49$), 
 what are the odds of getting $4$ out of $6$ numbers correct and then the correct powerball?

Thank you for your help.

PS. I got (a) $.000969$ or $1$ out of $1032.4$ 
 and (b) $.000097$ or $1$ out of $10324.$

But I have A as marked wrong on my paper.

This is what I did:

Ways to get $4$ of $6$ numbers correct  $C(6,4)=\large\frac{6!}{4!2!}$

Ways to get $2$ incorrect $C(43,2)=903.$

All possible combinations to win $C(49,6)=13983816.$

Then Probability of get $4$ out of $6$ of the white balls (there being as of yet no red ball)

$\large \frac{(C(6,4)* C(43,2)}{C(49,6)}$

For (B) I worked like this:

Probability is  $\large \frac{C(6,4)*C(43,2)*C(1,1)}{C49,6)*C(10,1)}$

with $C(1,1)=1$ and $C(10,1)=10.$

Comment: The second is one-tenth of the first, so cannot be $0.00097$. Just a typo.

Comment: Note that the numbers like $\binom{6}{4}$ are not probabilities,they are counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of A is fine, but B the decimal should have one more zero.  The chance of B is one tenth the chance of A, as your expression says.

Comment: I am confused because the decimal already is move over a tenth. I am very sorry, but I think I am missing something here. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I see three zeros before the 9 in both cases.  The conversion between $0.00097$ and $1$ in $10324$ is not correct.

Comment: Thank you, I mistyped that. So is it now correct that you can see?

Comment: Yes, I agree now.

Comment: I appreciate very much this help. Thank you.